# Cannot login to Twitter with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Here is my code

```
driver_path = Service(r"C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_path)
driver.get('https://twitter.com/login/')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')))
name = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-1dz5y72 r-fdjqy7 r-13qz1uu')
name.send_keys('username')

next = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]')
next.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

However, Selenium cannot find the name box regardless of how I try to give different xpaths or classes. I also tried to login from different url's such as

```
driver.get('https://twitter.com/i/flow/login')
```

but still couldn't proceed to the next step. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

***Solution***

I see `name='text'` is unique in HTML DOM. SO there is a way better approach will be to induce `ExplicitWait`.

Code:

```
self.browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 30)
self.browser.get('https://www.twitter.com/login')

username_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "text")))
username_input.send_keys('send username here')
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

CSS selector will be:

```
input[name='text']
```

XPATH will be:

```
//input[@name='text']
```